# how can I send form data with image in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

I have created an application where I want to send user summited form data with an image uploaded by them, I am new to angular so i am quiet unware of this can any body please help me I have attached images of my code below

I am using an model for user summited data and formdata method to upload image how can i combine both

[enter image description here][1]
this is my image where i am creating api, highlighted area is where image is going i also want to send user submited data
[enter image description here][2]
this is the pic of my model
[enter image description here][3]
this is the pic of my form

thanks in advance

```
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoIHE.png
      [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/19My3.png
      [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PIMe.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code in image 1 that you had attached, kindly repeat the `formdata.append("key", value);` once again for appending your user model's data as well.

It would be something similar to this,

```
const formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("userData", this.userData.value);
formdata.append("image", this.uploadedFile.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below, an example to upload a file item. I'm using a FileList here, maybe you are too. Hopefully this help you.

```
endpoint: string = 'https://YOURAPI/upload/Pictures';

httpUploadPicture(file: FileList)
{
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('yourotherdata', yourotherdata);
    if (file) formData.append('File', file[0], file[0].name);

    this.http.post(this.endpoint, formData);
}
```